# Show names separated (Getting names from database)

Tags: php, mysql

In my database I have one column named `name` and in each row of that column I'm saving names like this `/Mary/Sam/Bob/Michael/`. To show the values in my page I need to separate them by breaking the line in each `/`. Can someone help me?

If I make one echo of my column I will get `/Mary/Sam/Bob/Michael/` but I want:

```
  Mary
  Sam
  Bob
  Michael
```

Comment: So in one row you're storing multiple names separated with a forward slash?

Comment: @DiddleDot yes is that, i can't changet because if i change it, it will fuc*** some other parts of the code

Comment: I would recommend that you handle this in the PHP layer.  Just replace `/` with `\n` and that should do it.

Comment: explode on `/` but why does your db contain that in the first place?

Comment: If you really can't change how you're storing the data then you can just use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). But if at all possible I would store each name in it's own row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$names=explode('/', $dbrow['name']);
foreach($names as $aname){
  echo $aname.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the explode function with array_filter function

```
$database_column_string = "/Mary/Sam/Bob/Michael/";

$names = array_filter(explode('/',trim($database_column_string )));
foreach($names as $name){
    echo $name;
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The explode function will fix your problem but you should be aware that the way you're using your database is violating the first normal form. Each record should have the same number of attributes.

Here is a guide to the normal forms http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm

You should redesign your database to have a table called, for example, Names(id, name)

Answer (score 0):

\n may not render a new line in the web browser. So it's better to replace \ with the `br` tag:

```
str_replace ("/" , "<br>" , "/Mary/Sam/Bob/Michael/");
```